# programmatically disable a ngbPanel in ng-bootstrap with Angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to disable a panel within the `ngb-accordion` through my `typescript component` script in **Angular**.

As an example I am considering the [First Documentation Example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) where I have enabled all the Panels and created a simple button which acquires the `ViewChild('acc')` and I am trying to access a panel which I can disable.

### Observation

the only possible way to do this is setting up an external parameter (boolean variable) which is used to trigger `[disabled]` flag within the `ngb-panel`.

I have the following example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-accordion-disabler).
Where one clicks the button to disable the desired panel. This is achieved by toggling the boolean variable which is passed to the `disabled` flag

I have tried `NgbAccordionConfig` according to the docs, but it only provides `.type` and `.closeOthers` as methods.

Is it actually possible to access the panel somehow like below and disable it?

```
 this.acc.panelName.disabled=true
```

Or should I stick to disabling as mentioned in my **Stackblitz** example

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: sorry for that ! I have changed it. @Bdrizzle